# How to return control from callback function or break the processing of array in middle array_filter processing

Tags: php, arrays

Can we break execution of callback once condition satisfied with one element of array?

ex .

```
$a = array(1,2,3,4,5);
foreach($a as $val){

    if ($val == 3){
      break;
    }

}
```

if we write call back for it, it will be as below

```
$result = array_filter($a, function(){
      if ($val == 3){
          return true;
        }
});
```

In callback it will go through all array element, in spite of  condition is being satisfied at 3. rest two elements 4, 5 will also go through callback

I want such function in callback, which will break callback one desired condition match and stop execution of rest of elements

Is is possible?

Comment: You then just make the call back as a proper function, the purpose of array_filter callback is as stated `Iterates over *each value* in the input array passing them to the callback function`

Comment: @ ajreal : can you suggest how can i achieve this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do that with [a static variable](http://php.net/manual/language.variables.scope.php). A static variable is of local scope inside the callback function but preserves its value between calls.

It behaves like a global variable in terms of its value, but with a local scope:

```
$callback = function($val)
{
    static $filter = false;

    if ($val == 3) {
        $filter = true;
    }

    return $filter;        
};
```

This callback will return `false` until `$val == 3`. It then will return `true`.

Comment: will it stop execution of array for rest of the elements after $val == 3 match?

Comment: No, not the execution. But it will preserve the elements like you want it. There is no way to tell `array_filter` to stop, it will always process all values of the array. If you want that, you need to create a loop and exit it your own.

Comment: Ok...so with callback function it is not possible? and will not to be correct way to achieve it with callback function as well?

Comment: Well, there is not so much right or wrong in programming. It's a tool and it depends what you want to do. As far as `array_filter` is concerned, this is strictly spoken **not** a solution and there **can never be one** as there is no way (as I already wrote) to tell the currently executing `array_filter` function to stop filtering. But if you make more clear what you are looking for, I'm pretty sure a useful suggestion can be given to you how to solve your problem.

Answer (score 5):

I dont think you can achieve this with array_filter, but you can do something like this:

```
$a = array(1,2,3,4,5);
try {
    array_walk($a, function($value, $key) use(&$a) {
        if ($value == 3){
            throw new Exception("condition match");
        }
        unset($a[$key]);
    });
}
catch(Exception $e) { }
var_dump($a);
```